# Different library like ASIHTTPRequest which support ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Is there any open source library like ASIHTTPRequest which support ARC ? I don’t want to use ASIHTTPRequest in my project an more and i don’t want to make -fno-objc-arc flag disable as well for any other library.

Comment: AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: You'll be hard-pressed to find a mature networking library that natively supports ARC.  What's wrong with `-fno-objc-arc`?

Comment: If you want to simply network connections and nothing more robust, check out https://github.com/0xSina/URLConnection

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago and I ended up using NSURLConnection. This [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) from the Apple Developer's Reference helped.

I can post some sample code, if you're interested.